# Changing variable's name in loop

Tags: php

I have more than 50 string. I need to put those string into one array. I try to use loop to create it. however I have trouble on auto increment var's name. `$string.$s`(`$string1, $string2`). It will become Undefined variable, Any way to change var's name?

```
$string0="ABC";
$string1="DEF";
$string2="GHI";
...


$data=array($string0, $string1, $string2...);

for($s=0; $s<50; $s++){
    $data[$s]=$string.$s;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't those values an array in the first place ...?

Comment: because my string will be very long, and it will have more than 100 strings

Comment: If you indent correctly your code, there won't be any difference, from a "reading" point of view, between an array containing 100 strings and 100 variable declaration.

Comment: Why don't you use the replace function of your usual editor?

Comment: Creating 100 strings, then creating an array that includes those 100 strings is much more inefficient as just doing $data[] = "ABC" in the first place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not

```
$string.$s;
```

But

```
${'string'.$s};
```

---

Needless to say, the best solution is:

```
$data = array(
    'ABC',
    'DEF',
    'GHI',
);
```

or

```
$data = array();
$data[] = 'ABC';
$data[] = 'DEF';
$data[] = 'GHI';
```

or

```
$data = array();
$data[0] = 'ABC';
$data[1] = 'DEF';
$data[2] = 'GHI';
```

---

You can also replace them by your editor's function.

I'll take one example, *Notepad++*.
(Japanese plug-in is set on, sorry)

Let's try like this:
[image]

## Points:

- Search by `(\$string)([0-9]+)(=)`
- Replace to `\1[\2]\3`
- Mode **Regex**

Comment: because my string will be very long, and more than 100 string. I don't want to make my code very mess

Comment: _“I don't want to make my code very mess”_ – then look up how including files works.

Answer (score 3):

something like this should work I guess :

```
for($s=0; $s<50; $s++)
{
    $myvar = "string" . $s;
    $data[$s]=$$myvar;
}
```